# JSON error: obj.OBJ.JSONException: Value <head><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSON object

Tags: android, json

Help to day i install my application to test but when i signup it i got this JSON error: obj.OBJ.JSONException: Value

Pls.help (My English is basic.)

Code 
http://codepad.org/JWgBaEit (.Java File)

Comment: Paste your code and reduce it to the minimum: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
You should also provide more details on your problem...

Comment: You should at least post the stacktrace for the error.

Comment: what is your json looks like?do you check it?